# How to show data in drop-down list using rest api in flutter

Tags: api, rest, flutter, dart, dropdown

Here is my [api data structure](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enamulhaque028/parse_json_flutter/master/info.json). Using this api, I have fetched data.

The source code is [here](https://github.com/enamulhaque028/drop_down_flutter). Now I want to show data(e.g. pROJTNAME) in a drop down list and user can select the list like the image below. How this can be achieved?

[image]

Here is **main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get_api/model.dart';
import 'package:get_api/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: JsonParseDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class JsonParseDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  const JsonParseDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Hi!'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<User>(
          future: NetService.fetchTickesInfo(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.hasData
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.projectInfos.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text(snapshot.data.projectInfos[index]?.pROJTNAME ??
                            '--'),
                        Text(snapshot.data.projectInfos[index]?.pROJTDESC ??
                            '--'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              : snapshot.hasError
                  ? Text('Something was wrong!: ${snapshot.error}')
                  : Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DropdownButton widget: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html

Comment: I am new in flutter. How can i use it in my case?